# How do i emulate iphone safari with WebView in Mac os?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, macos, webview, agent

I have change the User_Agent to @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0_1 like Mac OS X; zh-cn) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A306 Safari/6531.22.7" which doesnot work.
Any body can help me ?
Thx in advance.

Comment: The header is called `User-Agent`, not `User_Agent`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your WebView, you can specify the userAgent string…  [from Apple's Docs..](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> setCustomUserAgent:Sets the receiver’s custom user-agent string.

`- (void)setCustomUserAgent:(NSString *)userAgentString`

Parameters `userAgentString`

> The custom user-agent string. The user-agent string is used by websites to identify the client browser. The custom user-agent string is used for all URLs. If nil, then the receiver constructs a user-agent string that produces the best rendering results for each URL.

As far as the actual string to set it to...  how about...

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25
```

Answer (score 2):

you can download the developer tools (XCode) for iPhone development which includes an iOS Simulator. You can test websites with it, too.

Comment: I am not testing website,just develop a mac app with a webview,which i want to emlate iphone safari.

Comment: **@NeXT5tep** Your question can be interpreted in to ways. iPortable simply answered your exact question (how to emulate iPhone Safari in OSX). Aparently your application needs to pose like Mobile Safari, which can indeed be achieved by changing the header. Are you sure the user-agent has actually been changed? Check here: http://www.useragentstring.com/